Cache issue on old domain Example.com? How can I remove it from client browser
I am running React build on NGINX server on GCP VM. The issue I am facing is, earlier I was opening website as example.com when I added permanent redirection with NGINX config files to www.example.com it is getting treated as new website to browser where earlier example.com was opened. In private tab website is getting redirected to www.example.com. And in some browsers, normal tab where cache has been stored for example.com there it is not redirected to www.example.com and not reflecting any changes.
Here is my configuration file:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    # Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    root /var/www/html;  # Path to your React build folder
    index index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.html;  # Redirect all non-matching routes to index.html
    }

    # Serve static files normally
    location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png|woff2?|eot|ttf|otf|svg)$ {
        expires 6M;
        access_log off;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    # Deny access to hidden files
    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
    }
}

I just want where website is working as example.com there it should redirected to www.example.com and every time client visits to website it should show latest changes.
Please help.

Your problem description is hard to follow, I can't tell what exactly is supposedly going wrong. But the basic fact of the matter is - once a client has cached something, there isn't much you can do about that any more. You need to instruct clients on how you want to stuff to be handled regarding caching, before they are doing the caching. If a client has cached a resource, and is therefor not making a new request to the server - then your server can hardly influence the situation any more, obviously.

The 301 permanent HTTP redirect usually cached by the client browsers. Due to the return 301 https://$host$request_uri; line, you are redirecting http://www.example.com to https://www.example.com and http://example.com to https://example.com, which is in turn will be redirected to https://www.example.com; to get rid of the extra redirect, change that line to return 301 https://www,example.com$request_uri; All the browsers which currently cached your previous redirects should be somehow cache-cleared.

server {
listen 80;
server_name example.com www.example.com;
# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;

} i have changed to this but still where is cache near around 5-6 mb. There it is working on hard refresh but whenever i open new tab on same browser it is still redirecting me to example.com
